# Number of calls of hashCode() and equals() in case of HashSet.contains() if hashcode returns a constant value

Tags: java, hashcode

I have read through Java docs pages, but I am not able to explain, why number of calls of `hashCode()` and `equals()` is varying like this?

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
public class NumberOfCalls {
    int field;

    public int getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public NumberOfCalls(int field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println("In Hashcode method.");
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("In Equals Method");
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        NumberOfCalls other = (NumberOfCalls) obj;
        if (field != other.field)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberOfCalls object1 = new NumberOfCalls(5);
        NumberOfCalls object2 = new NumberOfCalls(6);
        NumberOfCalls object3 = new NumberOfCalls(5);
        Set<NumberOfCalls> set = new HashSet<NumberOfCalls>();
        set.add(object1);
        set.add(object2);
        Iterator<NumberOfCalls> it = set.iterator();
        System.out.print("Size of set is : " + set.size()
            + "\nObject fields values present in set are : ");
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(it.next().getField() + "   ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n---------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Now checking number of calls -- ");
        System.out.println("Object1 is present in set ? - " + set.contains(object1)+"\n");
        System.out.println("Object2 is present in set ? - " + set.contains(object2)+"\n");
        System.out.println("Object3 is present in set ? - " + set.contains(object3)+"\n");
    }
}
```

Output for above code is

> In Hashcode method.
>   In Hashcode method.
>   In Equals Method
>   Size of set is : 2
>   Object fields values present in set are : 6   5
>
> ---------------------------------------------------
>   Now checking number of calls -- 
>   In Hashcode method.
>   In Equals Method
>   Object1 is present in set ? - true
>
> In Hashcode method.
>   Object2 is present in set ? - true
>
> In Hashcode method.
>   In Equals Method
>   In Equals Method
>   Object3 is present in set ? - true

Questions:

1. Why `hashCode()` and `equals()` called one-one time in case of `object1` but not `object2` (only `hashCode()` is called in this case)?
2. Why `equals()` is called twice in case of `object3`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add an element to a `Set` it gets stored in a `Map` internally where key is the object you pass in and value is set to `null`. Internally `Map` maintains an array (buckets) of linked list. These arrays can also be referred as buckets. The index of the bucket is evaluated using `hashCode()` method.

In your case since hashCode() returns a constant value, all values put into Set will go in the same bucket. So for the first call `set.add(object1)` internal structure will be something like

> bucket [object1 -> null]

Since each bucket contains a linked list, elements stored in the list has a pointer to the next element. Since only one element is added to the list, pointer points to `null`.

For next call `set.add(object2)` data structure will look like

> bucket [object2 -> object1 -> null]

Now whenever you call `set.contains(some_object)`, `hashCode()` will be called to find out correct bucket. This call also returns reference to the first element.

**Answer to first question:**

So when you call `set.contains(object2)` it actually returns reference to `object2`. Now if you look at the `HashMap` class' code it first compares if this reference is same as the reference passed in, using `==` operator. Since in this case it is same so it does not call `equals()` method. Below is the code snippet from `HashMap` class:

```
if (e.hash == hash &&
                ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                return e;
```

This should explain your first question.

**Answer to second question:**

When you call `set.contains(object3)`, bucket index is calculated and reference to `object2` is returned. Now `object2 == object3` returns false so Map calls `object3.equals(object2)` method (first call to `equals()` method) to check if both objects are meaningfully equivalent. This also returns `false`, so it traverses list and returns reference to the next element in the list, which is `object1`.

Again `object1 == object3` returns false so Map calls `object3.equals(object1)` (second call to `equals()` method) method to check if both objects are meaningfully equivalent.

This results in 2 calls to `equals()` method.

Comment: If that's the case you can mark this answer as 'Accepted' :)